# Check if time since last click is greater than 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, function, date, time

If found how to do this thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330638/calculating-the-time-between-two-clicks-in-javascript#2330660), but as you can see by the code bellow I'm trying to `console.log('Done');` when the time since the last click is greater than 2 seconds. However this doesn't work.

```js
var lastClick =  0;
var button_pressed = false;

let button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
let button2 = document.getElementById('button2');

button1.onclick = function() {
  button_pressed = true;
  CheckAnswer();
}

button2.onclick = function() {
  button_pressed = true;
  CheckAnswer();
}

function CheckAnswer() {
  if(button_pressed === true) {
    var d = new Date();
    var t = d.getTime();
    if(t - lastClick < 2000) {
      console.log('Continue');
    }
  } else if (t - lastClick > 2000) {
    console.log('Done');
  }
  lastClick = t;
}
```

```html
<button id="button1">Button1</button>
<button id="button2">Button2</button>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The problem is, button_pressed is always true once a button is pressed ... so `else if (t - lastClick > 2000) ` will **never** be checked

Comment: Yes, like pim's answer pointed out, my if statement was in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code never reaches the else if, because it requires `button_pressed` to be `false` 
I fixed your code, see below.
The `else if` is now declared withtin the `button_pressed === true` statement.

```
function CheckAnswer() {
  if(button_pressed === true) {
    var d = new Date();
    var t = d.getTime();
    if(t - lastClick < 2000) {
      console.log('Continue');
    } else {
       console.log('Done');
    }
  }
  lastClick = t;
}
```

Comment: `if (t - lastClick > 2000)` is almost redundant ... - the only time that will be reached, and false, is if the button is pressed exactly 2000ms after the previous press :p (but the code works as the description wants - so I didn't downvote)

Comment: Agreed, I glanced over that part to quickly. Fixed it in the reply... Thanks!

Comment: How would I check this without having to click the button again?

Comment: @Windclay what do you mean? (what do you want to check without clicking the button again?)

Comment: In my code I call the function when I press a button, but how would I check if the time since the last click is greater than 2 outside the function, so that it does it automatically and I don't have to call the CheckAnswer function again.

Comment: Depends on when you want to check it. You could use an [interval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function to trigger code after two seconds.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var lastClick = Date.now();
var button_pressed = false;

let button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
let button2 = document.getElementById('button2');

button1.onclick = function() {
  button_pressed = true;
  CheckAnswer();
}

button2.onclick = function() {
  button_pressed = true;
  CheckAnswer();
}

function CheckAnswer() {
  var t = Date.now();
  var diff = t - lastClick;
  if(diff < 2000) {
      console.log('Continue');
  } else {
      console.log('Done');
  }
  lastClick = t;
}
```

```html
<button id="button1">Button1</button>
<button id="button2">Button2</button>
```